# How to properly set timestamps of a target file in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, metadata

I'm using ffmpeg to concat multiple files into one consolidated file, but the resulting timestamp of the file created naturally falls on the time of this operation. I'm instead trying to set the timestamp of the new file to have the same matching created timestamp as the first file concatenated, and for that I'm using the following command:

```
ffmpeg.input('merge_list.txt', format='concat', safe=False).output(i, c='copy', **{'metadata:s:v:0': 'rotate=0'}, metadata=f'creation_time={creation_time}').run()
```

there are also a couple other modified metadata things, but most importantly I've modified the creation time here. the issue with this approach is that all this does is modify the *video* metadata, and not the actual file metadata, as shown here:

[image]

and here, through exiftool:

[image]

what is the best way to mirror the original file's timestamp data as close as possible (in the original file, both the video metadata and file metadata are accurate) to make the target file effectively look "correct" like the original file would?

Comment: ffmpeg can't alter the filesystem records for a file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959250/powershell-change-the-timestamp-date-created-of-a-folder-or-file

Comment: that is what I've seen, yeah... I've been thinking about using exiftool, but I don't know how I'm supposed to transfer the file data from one file to another. is this a valid method and if so, how?

Comment: It would depend upon the file names and directory structure, but the basic exiftool command would `exiftool -TagsFromFile Source.mp4 -FileCreateDate -FileModifyDate target.mp4`  This could be altered to copy the timestamps in batch by using exiftool's percent variables (`%d`, `%f`, `%e`) , see the [`-TagsFromFile` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#tagsFromFile-SRCFILE-or-FMT) and the [`-w` (`-TextOut`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#w-EXT-or-FMT--textOut)

Comment: this makes a bunch of sense, thanks so much! will do!

Comment: Just to clarify, is it the Created, Modified and Accessed date you are trying to copy. As in the files Properties dialog ?

Comment: actually, modified isn't something I particularly care about as I'm planning to upload this to block storage where metadata doesn't really matter; however, I do have a script that uses the created date to timestamp the file. but yes, Created date most importantly

Answer (score 0):

SyncStamper is an old app, but it's portable, so should work on most Windows versions. Extremely useful for simple transferring of Creation, Modified and Accessed data.

https://moochos.nobody.jp/en/software/syncstamper/index.html

Firstly, I recommend enabling **Topmost** in Options.

To transfer Created, Modified and Accessed info from one file to another, just drag your file with desired timestamps to the **Get** square. Next, drag your new file to the **Sync** square. That's it.

You can drag multiple files for batch syncing, but you must drag the same number of files onto each  square, and the files to be synced must be in the same directory order as the original files for correct syncing.